# Ajax запрос, как обращаться по IP?

Tags: ajax

У меня есть IP адрес сервера, и я хочу общаться с ним Ajax, но обычно я делаю это по url, например:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "script.php",
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            type: type
        },success: function(data) {
    
        }
    });
```

Как мне стоит обратиться по IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://IP_Сервера/script.php",
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
        type: type
    },success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Благодарю, спасибо!